# Dual password authentication in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Been trying out some python as I learnt a bit in school and I've been trying to make a simple login system with password authentication.

The way I want it to work:
get username and password,
ask for password for authentication and if password is not correct then ask again until it gets the right one

this is my code so far:

```
#online auth

email = input('What is your email address?')
password = input('Enter a password')
passcheck = input('Please re-enter password for confimation')

while passcheck != password:
    input('Please re-enter password for confirmation')

else: print("A confirmation code has been emailed to you")
```

When I run the program it asks for the email and username properly and then I get the confirmation question. If i enter the same password as the one i inputted in the first place it proceeds to the else statement. If i enter the wrong one it ends a never ending loop of reenter the password, even if i input the correct one.

I know that the while loop created an infinite loop but I cant find any good way to end it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
email = input('What is your email address?')
password_input = False
while not password_input or pass_check != password:
    password = input('Enter a password')
    pass_check = input('Please re-enter password for confimation')
    password_input = True
print("A confirmation code has been emailed to you")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, I actually just literally figured it out with the help of my friend. The issue was when I did the while loop, I didnt reassign the passcheck variable. This is it:
#online auth

email = input('What is your email address?')

password = input('Enter a password')

passcheck = input('Please re-enter password for confimation')

while passcheck != password:
    passcheck = input('Please re-enter password for confirmation')

else: print("A confirmation code has been emailed to you")


however thanks bro, I'll have a look at your code and how it works anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Just solved with the help of my friend:

```
#online auth

email = input('What is your email address?')
password = input('Enter a password')
passcheck = input('Please re-enter password for confimation')

while passcheck != password:
    passcheck = input('Please re-enter password for confirmation')
else: print("A confirmation code has been emailed to you")
```

Answer (score 0):

a good way to end a loop is to either use a for, or a counter variable

```
for index in range(0,5):
    password = input('Enter a password')
    pass_check = input('Please re-enter password for confimation')
    if pass_check == password :
        print("A confirmation code has been emailed to you")
        index=65532
    else :
        print("The passwords do not match, try again.")

if index != 65532 :
    print("too many attempts, if you want to retry, please restart the program")
```

note : the 65532 is not special, it's just out of range, so you exit the for.